# how to make gradient animation in image with css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-size

so, I have a gallery that has description/ title for each image in the bottom of the image. I made for each gallery line has four images, and all images have same size.

this is the HTML code:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="image1.png">
        <div class="desc">some description</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="image2.png">
        <div class="desc">some description</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="image3.png">
        <div class="desc">some very long description</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <div class="flag">
        <img src="image4.png">
        <div class="desc">some description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the CSS code:

```
.gallery {
            padding: 6px 6px;
            float: left;
            width: 24.99999%;
        }
.flag {
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          padding: 5px;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px black;
        }
.flag img {
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px black;
        }
.desc {
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            font-color: black;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
```

My problem is, if some images has long description like image3.png, the height of .desc will be higher than the other, and I have many images in my gallery, so it will makes the gallery not in order. My question is, how to make the font-size from some images with long description is responsive with the .desc size? and the rest of images stay still with the font-size from .desc. Any suggestion? thanks before

Comment: You will need a script to do that, checking the height on `.desc` and if to high, change font until it is not ...or if you generate this server side, you could count characters and add a class to the element for the one's that is too long

Comment: can u give me an example from script? @LGSon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution will be to create a new selector that has a smaller font size and only apply it in those cases you see the font-size is affecting another image. Like this:

```
   <div class="gallery">
<div class="flag">
    <img src="image4.png">
    <div class="desc myNewSelector">some description</div>
</div>
```

```
        .desc {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        font-color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
        .myNewSelector {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I didnt notice it will be this simple :D

Comment: @Rian Well, it is not that simple, as when someone resize, or have a less wide screen, it might need 3 lines instead of 2, and the issue will appear again.